# Проблема с сервером WildFly 11

Tags: java, rest, wildfly

Всем привет!
Такой вопрос, есть сайт, написан на HTML, к нему написан Restful web service, использую веб сервер WildFly 11, и проблема заключается в том, что при отображении страниц вместо русских текстов отображаются непонятные символы. Ссылки на страницы указываю через web.xml вот так вот:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>account</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/resources/pages/mainFrame.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>account</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/account</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

На HTML страницах тоже указывается вот так вот:

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-
     8"/>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/index.css" 
    type="text/css">-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="/SnackLanguage/resources/css/index.css" 
      type="text/css"/>
   <title>Snack Language</title>
</head>
```

Вот то что в настройках сервера в админ панеле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот то что в настройках сервлетов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот то что получаю в браузере: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто может помочь исправить эти кракозябры?

Comment: Подозреваю, проблема в том, что вы зачем-то в теге `<jsp-file>` указали html-файл. Контейнер undertow сам отдаёт html-файлы, без маппинга.

Comment: Что мне тогда нужно сделать, что бы исправить это?

Comment: Либо убрать из web.xml маппинг, либо использовать jsp.

Comment: Это не помогло.

Comment: а html файл если просто локально открыть (без сервера) как он выглядит? с теми же кракрзябрами?

Comment: Я уверен, что проблема именно в сервере. Потому что я сейчас переделал отображение страниц через сервлеты и в самом сервлете устанавливаю кодировку для респонса, и вот только теперь отображается нормально без кракозябр.